# How do you clear scope in one controller from another controller in AngularJS?

Tags: service, message, controllers, angularjs, alerts

I'm trying to create a simple messaging service (see jsFiddle) using AngularJS and it's working for the most part. However, my "clearAlerts()" method doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm new to Angular, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/j46Yh/

...and the code

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

function AlertsCtrl($scope, alertsManager) {
    $scope.alerts = alertsManager.alerts;
}

function FooCtrl($scope, alertsManager) {
    $scope.doGood = function() {
        alertsManager.addAlert('Yay!', 'alert-success');
    };
    $scope.doEvil = function() {
        alertsManager.addAlert('Noooo!', 'alert-error');
    };
    $scope.reset = function() {
        alertsManager.clearAlerts();
    };
}

App.factory('alertsManager', function() {
    return {
        alerts: {},
        addAlert: function(message, type) {
            this.alerts[type] = this.alerts[type] || [];
            this.alerts[type].push(message);
        },
        clearAlerts: function() {
            this.alerts = {}; // <= not working??
        }
    };
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pawel Kozlowski was kind of enough to provide my answer via the [AngularJS mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/angular). I simply had to change one line in my AlertsCtrl...

```
function AlertsCtrl($scope, alertsManager) {
    $scope.alertsManager = alertsManager;
}
```

Check out the [new working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/j46Yh/6/)

Comment: Also, changing that one line didn't fix the fiddle you posted in your OP.

Comment: I accidentally deleted the fiddle. Here's one that works. http://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/j46Yh/6/

Comment: Oh cool. That's really interesting that's the requirement for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to just remove the properties on the alerts.

http://jsfiddle.net/j46Yh/4/

```
    clearAlerts: function() {
        for(var x in this.alerts) {
           delete this.alerts[x];
        }
    }
```

Comment: here's the final version. for deleting, the copy() method was recommended to me... http://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/HU4Eu/

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for commenting with it.